# Как перевернуть двумерный массив Поменять последнюю строку с первой, предпоследнюю со второй и т. д.?

Tags: javascript

Данный код меняет местами только первую и последнюю строчку, но не меняет местами 2 и 3 строчку

```js
// перевернуть двумерный массив Поменять последнюю строку с первой, предпоследнюю со второй и т. д.
// Условие: матрица должна быть квадратной.

function Trans(Array, n) {
  for (var i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; i++, j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < n; k++) {
      temp = Array[i][k];
      Array[i][k] = Array[j][k];
      Array[j][k] = temp;
    }
    // вывод полученного массива
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      document.writeln(Array[i]);
      document.writeln("<br>");
    }
  }
  return Array
}

var Array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [4, 5, 6, 4],
  [7, 8, 9, 4],
  [-1, -2, -3, 5]
];
var n = Array.length; // кол-во строк и столбцов
var temp = 0;
document.writeln("<p>");
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  document.writeln(Array[i]);
  document.writeln("<br>");
}

document.writeln("<p>");
Array = Trans(Array, n);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function Trans(Array, n) {
>   for (var i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; i++, j++) { // <-- ошибка 1 и 2
>     for (var k = 0; k < n; k++) {
>       temp = Array[i][k];
>       Array[i][k] = Array[j][k];
>       Array[j][k] = temp;
>     }
>
>     // вывод полученного массива
>     for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
>       document.writeln(Array[i]);
>       document.writeln("<br>");
>     }
>   } // <-- ошибка 3
>   return Array
> }
> ```

Пара ошибок в том, что ваш код:

1. увеличивает (`j++`) вместо того чтобы уменьшать (и выходит за границы массива)
2. цикл продолжает пока `i < n`, вместо `i < j` (то есть все поменяется местами 2 раза и получится то же, что и было в начале).
3. и неверно сделан вывод полученного массива - вы его выводите изнутри цикла по обмену подмассивов, а должны бы по окончании, снаружи (и, соответственно портите `i`, как верно указал @Igor)

P.S. Как подсказывает @Igor, менять местами можно сразу подмассивы, вместо поэлементного обмена.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var Array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  ['Vera', 'luba', 'Zina'],
  ['Makar', 'Grisha', 'Viniamin'],
  ['Net', 'Da']
];


var rev = Array.reverse();


console.log(rev);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Print(Array, n) {
  document.writeln("<p>");
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    document.writeln(Array[i]);
    document.writeln("<br>");
  }
}

function Trans(Array, n) {
  for (var i = 0, j = n - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
    var temp = Array[i];
    Array[i] = Array[j];
    Array[j] = temp;
  }
  return Array;
}


var Array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [4, 5, 6, 4],
  [7, 8, 9, 4],
  [-1, -2, -3, 5]
];
var n = Array.length; // кол-во строк и столбцов

Print(Array, n);
Array = Trans(Array, n);
Print(Array, n);
```

Третья ошибка (в дополнение к двум от @Kromster): переменные `var i` в двух циклах функции `Trans` - это одна и та же переменная. Внутренний цикл доводит ее до `n`, таким образом, внешний цикл выполняется только один раз.